# Ag grid: Autosizing columns at run time not working in chrome/IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have Ag grid in angular framework in which after initial load of data, I am applying grouping dynamically (row grouping) after that I am trying to expand all the groups and once grid is grouped and rows are expanded I want to autosize columns to avoid showing ellipses (value...).

In below plunker I have reproduced the issue. I see that after grouping, I used hack setTimeout function to expand/collapse or autosize columns it works.

[Autosize columns plunker using hack setTimeout, check app.component.ts file](https://plnkr.co/edit/R4dbvZzJFDZkiWwfVyss?p=preview)

I dont want to use this hacky approach because I dont know the exact number of rows(data) so in some cases setTimeout will not work.

Also its very slow in IE11 and there it may require more timeout value.

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        data[0].athlete = 'very very very long text very very very long text very very very long text very very very long text'
        this.rowData = data;
         this.gridColumnApi.addRowGroupColumns(["sport", "year", "country", "athlete"]);

        // This will not work
        // this.setDefaultExpanded();

        // This will work (hacky solution)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setDefaultExpanded();
        }, 1000);

        // This will not work
        // this.autoSizeAll();

        // This will work (hacky solution) 
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.autoSizeAll();
        }, 2000);

      });
  }



 setDefaultExpanded() {
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
        if (node.group) {
            node.expanded = true;
          }
        });
        this.gridApi.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
  }


  autoSizeAll() {
      const allColumnIds = [];
      if (this.gridColumnApi) {
        this.gridColumnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().forEach(column => {
          allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
        });
        this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
      }

  }
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: try using settimeout in code setTimeout(function(){ this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);},200)

Comment: I worked long back but whenever I face an issue like this will use timeout function but I am not sure if it is good practice. Please confirm if it works

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am already trying that, and I don't want to use this hack (setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Please use **onFirstDataRendered** event. This will be fired once the data is loaded to the grid.

```
var gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
        resizable: true
    },
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    onFirstDataRendered: onFirstDataRendered
};

function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
    const allColumnIds = [];
  if (this.gridColumnApi) {
    this.gridColumnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().forEach(column => {
      allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
    });
    this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried almost all the event of ag grid firstDataRendered, modelUpdated, rowDataChanged, rowDataUpdated. The problem here is that autosize gets called before expand/collapse operation, because its asynchronous callback of forEachNode. And also in my case the grid gets refreshes in every 5 seconds so doing autosize on such events will be more costlier.

Comment: you can post in Github issues also. sorry I couldn't find fix

Comment: sure will reach to ag grid community but thanks for your response